# Get all tr in table between tr with table-primary class and push in array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, html-table

At the click of the button #create-arrays I need to create multiple arrays. Each array will contain the set of tr (not .table-primary) present between the two tr (previous and next) with class table primary. this set of tr will be called context. Using jquery, how can I identify any such context and place it in an array? Thanks to everyone who will help.

HTML part (for testing):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td colspan="2">Group 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Jonh</td>
          <td>Surname: Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Mark</td>
          <td>Surname: Lon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td colspan="2">Group 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Will</td>
          <td>Surname: Man</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Ben</td>
          <td>Surname: Harper</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Mitch</td>
          <td>Surname: Collins</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td colspan="2">Group 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Serena</td>
          <td>Surname: Mellin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td colspan="2">Group 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Nickolas</td>
          <td>Surname: Malinof</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: David</td>
          <td>Surname: Benner</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Lenny</td>
          <td>Surname: Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Micheal</td>
          <td>Surname: Pitzford</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: Melania</td>
          <td>Surname: Bebant</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the jquery script that i use to get all the tr inside tbody.

```
$('#create-arrays').on('click', function(){

    var context = [];
    var a = $('#file_table_available tbody tr');
    console.log(a);
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            const element = a[i];
        }
    })
```

Comment: `$('tr:not('.table-primary')` will create a jQuery object containing the elements you want to target. You can use `map()` from there if you need to create an array from them, but creating an array of `tr` Elements from a jQuery object seems redundant when you already have the jQuery object to work from. Depends on your use case though.

Comment: What are these arrays for? Explaining use case in more detail would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good start looping over all rows in the table.

You could check each row (`element` in your snippet) for the existance of the `table-primary` class. If the row has this class, you know you have to create a new group.

Here's a vanilla javascript example. It outputs an array of groups. Each group contains 1 or more rows that belong together.

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

const groups = [];
let group = null;

for (const row of rows) {
  if (row.classList.contains("table-primary")) {
    group = [];
    groups.push(group);
  } else {
    group.push(row);
  }
}

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-primary">
      <td colspan="2">Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Jonh</td>
      <td>Surname: Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Mark</td>
      <td>Surname: Lon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-primary">
      <td colspan="2">Group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Will</td>
      <td>Surname: Man</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Ben</td>
      <td>Surname: Harper</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Mitch</td>
      <td>Surname: Collins</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-primary">
      <td colspan="2">Group 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Serena</td>
      <td>Surname: Mellin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-primary">
      <td colspan="2">Group 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Nickolas</td>
      <td>Surname: Malinof</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: David</td>
      <td>Surname: Benner</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Lenny</td>
      <td>Surname: Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Micheal</td>
      <td>Surname: Pitzford</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name: Melania</td>
      <td>Surname: Bebant</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```